# Table view line separators like in Notification Center in iOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7

I would like to have the same effect on the table view line separators shown in Notification Center.
If you pay close attention to them they don't have a solid colour and it's not an image either.

[image]

Anyone have a good idea how I can do the same?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try anything to achieve this effect on your own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a sample project that shows one possible way to achieve this kind of effect with public API.

https://github.com/mikrohard/BluredTableView

Answer (score 0):

First create a custom table view cell with a transparent background.  Then add a thin `UIView` to the bottom/top of the cell as the separator.  Make its background color white and make it semi-transparent.

Comment: Hi @Jonathan,
 It's close but not what I'm expecting.
 It seems like the lines have a screen filter on the background.
 And BTW, it will be easier to do this: `tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0f alpha:0.2];`

Answer (score 0):

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath  *)indexPath
{
     UIImageView *sepImgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"colored_line.png"]];
     sepImgView.frame = CGRectMake(20, myCellHeight, myCellWidth, 1);
     [cell.contentView addSubview:sepImgView];
     return cell; 
}
```

And you need to set your seperator style to `UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone`

Comment: If you really pay attention to those lines in your iPhone, you can see that they are not a static image.

Comment: Yup I know and I did pay attention, but I guess this is the closest you can get, since setting separator Alpha will not give you even close to what you want, I think Apple guys use a kind of filter on the table layer or one of their unofficial trick. Anyway +1 for your good question.